# How do Professional Killstreaks work?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I'm going to buy a **Strange**, **Professional Killstreak** weapon.

I have a sever where it lets you farm kills, I want to use it for the **strange** quality, I can get to 5000 kills in 30 minutes with the server.

I know that professional killstreak makes your weapon glow for the certain killstreak count 5-20, **Red, Blue, Pink, Orange, Yellow, Bright Green, Subdued Green, and Purple** but...

My question is: is the glowing effect permanent for each stage, and will it stay like that? If I farm on the server, and get 1000 kills, will I completely bypass the other colors, and go straight to purple really quickly, and won't be able to get the other previous colors EVER, or does it reset every time I join a new server.
And does it go with the same thing with particle effect to the user's eyes?

Reason for this question, I want to see the different colors, but I also want to get to **Hale's own** 5000 kills on the strange.

Comment: Relevant to a deleted question you asked earlier: this is the only post you have that is not deleted with downvotes. I didn't downvote, so I can't say for sure, but I would not be even remotely surprised if you're getting downvotes because you're asking about farming kills to artificially get something that others have earned. Many people would consider that "lame", which one could consider "not useful". Also, it looks like all the info in the answer came from one wiki page, so there's also lack of research. If you really want to know why you're getting downvotes, post a question on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sheen colors glow regardless of how many kills you have, in addition it does not change colors depending on how many kills you get. With Professional kits you get the following effects which are visible on the user's eyes once you reach a killsteak milestone.

The list of effects are:

```
Cerebral Discharge
Fire Horns
Flames
Hypno-Beam
Incinerator
Singularity
Tornado
```

Source: [Killstreak kits](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Killstreak_Kit)

Comment: Thank You, I was just curious because I saw a guy join a new server and he already had a purple glowing effect on his rocket launcher.